# Implement an Offline-mode for the Windows UWP WebView

Tags: visual-studio, webview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows WUP app with a WebView which is loading a webpage from the internet. Now, if the user is offline, I want to display a local version of this page. The webpage changes once a day, and it is displays only a basic table.

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is webpage in question is static or dynamic?

Comment: if it's static you can always bundle it along with your project and load local file.

Comment: Now my problem is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your web page in the local file for example as a string, to return the response body as a string, you can create a new instance of [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx).

Here is a method, in the `NavigationCompleted` event of your `WebView`, code like this:

```cs
private async void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSuccess == true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (args.Uri != null && args.Uri.ToString() == "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop")
                {
                    var htmlstring = await client.GetStringAsync(args.Uri);
                    StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                    StorageFile file = await local.CreateFileAsync("offline-web.html", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
                    {
                        writer.Write(htmlstring);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await local.GetFileAsync("offline-web.html");
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
            {
                var htmlstring = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                sender.NavigateToString(htmlstring);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Please check your internet", "Warning");
            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also try other methods, for example save the html file, and navigate to the local file. And as @Amod Gokhale said, if there is some dynamic objects need to be loaded with Internet, then in the offline-mode, these objects will not be loaded even you saved the html page unless you also saved all the resources of these dynamic objects.